# Remove <p> tag in spooling xls file using SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Can anyone help me to remove < p > tag in start of SQLPLUS output when using MARKUP HTML ON.
[image: SQLPLUS output]

This is my code.

[image: My code]

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure if this is possible at all. However, I see you are exporting data to an Excel file.

Don't know if Excel opens html files but it does open CSVs which is easy to export data to. Just write the following command

```
set markup csv on delimiter ';'
```

instead of "set markup html"

Here is an example of what I get

```
set markup csv on delimiter ';'
select 1 col_1, 'some_val' col_2 from dual;

"COL_1";"COL_2"
1;"some_val"
```

And Excel successfully recognizes such an output as a valid csv file.

Hope this will help

Comment: @beginneronly that was an interesting question. Let me know if that worked or not